# ng-admin redirect to specific page after element creation

Tags: angularjs, ng-admin

I have a small admin page setup with ng-admin. Creating elements works without any issues.

What I want to achieve though is that I sent the user to a different page where he can perform some action that will alter the created item(scraping some data elsewhere for the element and asking if its correct).

Is there a way to overwrite the custom route that is on the submit button in ng-admin to sent the user to a custom page, also inside of ng-admin?

I would like to not tinker with the ng-admin code to not break the functionality on other elements pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tere is no built-in way to do that in ng-admin 0.9. But a recent addition to the 1.0.0-dev branch (`view.prepare()`) might help you, see https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/pull/756.